# attach crossbar for ceiling suspended shelves using strong Simpson ties

Tags: garage, shelving

While constructing a ceiling suspended shelves in garage I was facing problems with attaching crossbar to ceiling joist I just couldn't get lag through 2x4 into middle of joist it was always off and I wasn't sure of how well is the connection.

So I looked into this [strong tie](https://www.strongtie.com/deckties_decks/dpt_tie/p/dptz) which kind of seemed like good solution to my problem and also since it connects 2x4 on edge it will give more surface area to connect vertical members.
My question are

1. Will it provide strong connection with crossbar and joist for shelves to hold say 300-400 pounds?
2. Does it matters where the vertical members are attached on crossbar or do they must be on where crossbar is fastened to the joist?
3. Should I use nails or screws to mount the brackets?

If it helps I have  room with full bath over the garage 
Hopefully this rough sketch can give some idea how I am thinking to attach crossbar to joist using strong ties 
[image]

Comment: Seems adding more parts  isn't a good remedy for your inability to drill a straight hole. Anyway, I'm not clear on how the brackets are being used. Please provide a photo or sketch.

Comment: It's not inability with drilling straight holes its with matching joist placing with holes on crossbar , I'll see if I can sketch something till then , the idea is strong ties will go over 2x4 on edge and connect with joist which will be perpendicular to crossbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That's going to depend on the fastener you use. For a vertically-suspended mount like this it's critical that you use a screw with enough thread area, or that you use through-bolts. I'd use 3/8" lag screws of 2-1/2" length or 5/16" machine bolts running all the way through the joist and nutted on top. Dividing your 400 lb. load in half gives us 200 lbs. per bracket, and 100 lbs. per screw. That's likely to hold well. Test safely first. Watch for deflection of the crossbar and deformation of the brackets.
2. A 2x4 on edge will carry a substantial load, but I wouldn't hang that much weight further than about 16" from the brackets. If you see a lot of flex, move closer.
3. See #1. Nails are almost never a good choice for load-bearing applications, and certainly not for direct suspension. You must use a threaded fastener of adequate diameter or a through-bolt with a suitable washer and nut.

I would consider using [standard joist hangers](https://www.strongtie.com/facemounthangersssl_solidsawnlumberconnector/lus-hus-hhus-hgus_productgroup_wcc/p/lus.hus.hhus.hgus) and placing your crossbars between the joists, or simply lay your crossbar on top of the joists, if that suits your needs. Either is a much stronger method than vertical fasteners.